# Forbidden Handler in SharePoint custom login with ADFS

Tags: sharepoint, adfs

I've run into an issue of Forbidden 403 page in SharePoint 2010 with ADFS custom login page.

I've configured SharePoint to use ADFS as identity provider and I want Custom login page inplace of ADFS default login page.

I've created an Application page and placed it in Layouts folder and configured this path in Custom Sign In section under Authentication providers for my SharePoint page.

When I navigate to my SharePoint site, it redirects  the page to my Custom Sign In page, but with the forbidden handler.

I've given all the permission to the Bin directory and still could not get through the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What baseclass did the codebehind for your application page inherit from? It is important that it inherits from Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.

Furthermore, to allow anonymous users access to this page the following property must be set:

```
protected override bool AllowAnonymousAccess
{
    get
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably being redirected to 403, because anonymous user not having access to display the custom error page.

Log files can give you a clue on why is that happening.

Alternatively:

In web.config files (one for the web application & the one in _layouts folder) set the following:

CustomErrors="Off"
Debug="true"
Callstack="true"

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was related to the Master Page being used (source linked below).

Remove DynamicMasterPageFile = “~/masterurl/default.master” attribute and add MasterPageFile=”/_Layouts/15/ErrorV15.master” attribute at @Page directive in .aspx page. You can also use Simple.master or SimpleV4.master pages.

https://hpatel.wordpress.com/2014/06/29/sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-anonymous-application-page/